# mvc4 ajax updating same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a list of users on a page, they are loaded during an ajax event when I click on a tab (easytabs).  I then ajax load a create new user partial view to the same tab.  I then create a new user using this form, but I do not know how to re-load the first partial view with a new list of users (including the newly created user).

**HTML to load tab panel with list of users:**

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Manage Users", "tabsUsers", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ManageUsersPartial", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, htmlAttributes: new { data_target = "#tabs-users" })%>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult tabsUsers()
{
    return PartialView("UsersPartial", userManager.GetUsers());
}
```

**UsersPartial View**

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<LMS.Data.User>>" %>

<p>
    <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "CreateUserPartial", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })%>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email) %>
        </th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserID })%> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserID }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserID }) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>

</table>

<br />

<div id="CreateUserPartial"></div>
```

This works great, every time I click the tab, the data is re-loaded as expected.

Now,

In the UsersPartial view, I have another Ajax Actionlink that loads another partial view into this partial view, to create a new user:

**HTML Ajax Actionlink from UsersPartial View:**

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "CreateUserPartial", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })%>
```

This loads the following **CreateUserView view** inside of the UsersPartial view:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<LMS.Data.User>" %>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="result"></div>

<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Could not create new user.") %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

Finally, the code for CreateUser is called in the controller
**CreateUserPartial Controller code:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AccountUser user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                user.Password = user.Password.Encrypt();
                userManager.AddUser(user);
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbex)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException dbuex)
            {
                if (dbuex.InnerException != null)
                    if (dbuex.InnerException.InnerException != null)
                        if (dbuex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"))
                            return Content("User already exists!", "text/html");
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "An unknown error occured when creating the user.");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "An unknown error occured when creating the user.");
            }
        }

        return Content("User created!", "text/html");
    }
```

This all works...when a user is created, it says User created! as expected.

Now on to my question, how do I re-load the list within the UsersPartial view with the new user?  I cannot figure this part out.  I have a feeling it has to do with the jQuery ajax success method, but I do not know how to re-load the list of users, including this newly created one.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please don't Postback the form. Instead of that Call the ajax call**

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<LMS.Data.User>" %>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm())
 <%: Ajax.BeginForm("Create",new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ManageUsersPartial", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, htmlAttributes: new { data_target = "#tabs-users" })
   { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Could not create new user.") %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

**And then method should return the paratail view instead of Content Type**

```
    public ActionResult Create(AccountUser user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                user.Password = user.Password.Encrypt();
                userManager.AddUser(user);
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbex)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
return PartialView("CreateUserPartial", user);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException dbuex)
            {
                if (dbuex.InnerException != null)
                    if (dbuex.InnerException.InnerException != null)
                        if (dbuex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"))
                            return Content("User already exists!", "text/html");
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "An unknown error occured when creating the user.");
return PartialView("CreateUserPartial", user);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "An unknown error occured when creating the user.");
return PartialView("CreateUserPartial", user);
            }

return PartialView("UsersPartial", userManager.GetUsers());
        }

        return PartialView("UsersPartial", userManager.GetUsers());
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working... Returning that view keeps the original list on the top, and then shows the new list with the added user...I need the original list removed

Comment: Hey in your question.. you said that it should update the list when new user created so it will work.It will update the record with database.What do you mean by I need the original list removed ?Please explore your question.

Comment: Well, I finally figured it out.  Your solution was correct, however I had an error in my html.  I was updating the wrong div with the correct partial view.  Your response led me to the correct answer (for me), so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must return a new list after the create. Instead of:

```
return Content("User created!", "text/html");
```

You should do:

```
return PartialView("UsersPartial", userManager.GetUsers());
```

EDIT : your partial wants a `IEnumerable` of users. If you need a message, send it via the `ViewBag`.

Comment: I tried this, and it just appends the whole view, so it looks like they are stacked.

Comment: I tried this, and it just appends the whole view, so it looks like they are stacked, this is a View->Partial->Partial, I need it to re-load the parent partial view.  Using your code above, it simply shows two lists of users, one not updated (the original), and a new updated on.  Also, i'd like it to remove the CreateUserPartial if successful